# Twitter Streaming API unauthorized

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

I have a problem getting tweets from twitter streaming api: https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json

I always get error 401, unauthorized. Server time is correct.

I already sign request. 
Here is my code (python):

```
    token = oauth.Token(key = TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN, secret = TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
    consumer = oauth.Consumer(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)

    params = {'oauth_version': '1.0', 'oauth_nonce': oauth.generate_nonce(), 'oauth_timestamp': int(time.time())}
    req = oauth.Request(method='POST', parameters=params, url='https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=twitter')
    req.sign_request(oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), consumer, token)

    urllib2.urlopen(req.to_url())
```

What am I doing wrong?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance,
Sabrina

Answer (score 0):

You are either providing it with incorrect credentials or there is a bug causing the incorrect signature to be calculated. Setting log level to DEBUG might be helpful here.

Using my credentials from the [twitter application page](https://dev.twitter.com/apps) I had no problems fetching the stream using

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

key = "<your client key>"
secret = "<your client secret>"
token = "<your token here>"
token_secret = "<token secret>"

twitter = OAuth1Session(key, client_secret=secret,
                        resource_owner_key=token,
                        resource_owner_secret=token_secret)

r = twitter.get(
    'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=twitter',
    stream=True
)

for line in r.iter_lines():
    if line:
        print line
```

which uses [requests-oauthlib](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib). If the above works for you then your credentials are correct and the issue might be with your oauth library.